# iPhone development: what will [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] return for "iPad"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.2

What will [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] return for "iPad"?

Comment: This is under NDA, so your question is likely to be ignored until the NDA is lifted. The documentation states that `model` returns a string like "iPod Touch" or "iPhone" for those respective devices, so one cane make an educated guess..

Comment: @Jasarien: If I am not wrong the sdk version beta_5 is not under NDA, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Madhup, I believe it still is. At the iPhone Developer site, the warning is still in place that says: "iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 5 is pre-release software and is considered Apple Confidential Information." While it can be used to submit iPad apps, it is still under NDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`, which will either return `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` or `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`. Bear in mind that on any device < 3.2, this is unavailable, so first check to see whether the property can be retrieved - in this case, it is not an iPad.

Or, alternatively, to specifically work out whether the platform is an iPad or not, use

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] containsString:@"iPad"]) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 3):

I tried using containsString but it was not allowed with xcode4

Here is how I solved it:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
    {
```

Hope this helps even if its a bit late.

Answer (score 1):

Well trying on simulator:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
```

it gives **iPad Simulator**, will update the answer when I will get the device ;)

Comment: @g.revolution : then wait for somebody to get the device and post the answer ;)

Comment: tested this on an iPad 3G and it gave me "iPad" only. Was hoping to be bale to read 3G as well but was unlucky

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone/32beta).