# Detect if app is running in iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I can detect that app is running under *iOS Simulator* (using `sysctlbyname("hw.machine")`), but how do I know if it is iPad of iPhone simulator?

Of course I may check `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`, but probably there are more elegant way?

Comment: There's also a conditional that you can use instead of `sysctlbyname`: `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, just found that `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]` gives what I need.

Comment: If so, don't forget to accept your own answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

iPhone:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) { }
```

iPad:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look your current device model, like this:

```
[[UIDevice CurrentDevice] model];
```

Also, you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522418/iphone-development-what-will-uidevice-currentdevice-model-return-for-ipad) I think it will work for you.